# Joomla JMail code not working - Javascript works fine

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, email, joomla

I'll try to be thorough and brief here. I am currently working in Joomla for the first time, but I've developed before. I am using Joomla 3.4. What I am trying to do:
A user signs up for our newsletter through a specific page that directs them to a coupon.
The next page shows them the coupon and has an email tag in the URL (i.e. &email='email')
I am trying to code within a module to parse out that email and send a copy of the coupon to that users email automatically.

I can't use a general automatic email when any user subscribes, because only users that sign up from that specific page will get the coupon. I have turned all text filtering off and am using basic module editor. When I save the module, the code shows just fine in the edit box. When I viewed the source of the page, that script tags would still be there, but the code would all be blank. I have now gone into phpmyadmin and can edit the module directly there. Now, the script is showing up just fine.

I've tried many different fixes, including adding a `jQuery($)` function load in order to bypass any issues with mootools. Wondering if it was an issue with Javascript, I cleared the script and made a simple `alert("Testing...");` script that fired just fine on the page. This means that there must be something within my full script that is not working correctly. Any help or other ideas would be wonderful. I have spent over a day on this already and am at wits' end. Here's the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function get(name){
   if(name=(new RegExp('[?&]'+encodeURIComponent(name)+'=([^&]*)')).exec (window.location.search))
    $recipient = decodeURIComponent(name[1]);
}

$mailer = JFactory::getMailer();

$config = JFactory::getConfig();
$sender = array(
    $config->get( 'config.mailfrom' ),
    $config->get( 'config.fromname' )
);

$mailer->setSender($sender);

get('email');

$mailer->addRecipient($recipient);

$body = '<h2>Thank you for joining our mailing list!</h2>
    '<div>Here is your coupon for a FREE 8" 1-topping pizza at Goodfellas!'
    '<img src="http://www.goodfellas309.com/main/images/pizzacoupon.jpg" alt="pizza coupont"/></div>';
$mailer->isHTML(true);
$mailer->Encoding = 'base64';
$mailer->setSubject('Your Free Pizza!');
$mailer->setBody($body);

$send = $mailer->Send;
if ( $send !== true ) {
    echo 'Error sending email: ' . $send->__toString();
} else {
    alert("An email with your coupon has been sent to you! Thank you for joining our mailing list!");
}
');
</script>
```

I have even attempted an inline PHP parse through Joomla with this code wrapping the javascript:

```
<?php

$document = JFactory::getDocument();
$document->addScriptDeclaration('
-Javascript here-
');
?>
```

I've always loved StackOverflow, and the answered questions have gotten me out of so many jams. I just can't find the answer to this anywhere. Thanks for your time!

Comment: You have your javascript and php all mixed-up. The php part has no idea of what the js is doing and it has also no idea of where to send the email. Furthermore the included php code inside the `<script>` tags is not enclosed in `<?php ?>` tags so it won't be parsed at all as code. If you don't separate the two neither `get('email');` will do anything nor `alert("An email with...` will alert anything because it's js code inside php and not formatted properly.

Comment: The `<?php ?>` was a list ditch effort to fix the javascript not working. I just wanted to show that I tried things that I didn't even think would work, myself. The Joomla site showed that you could embed javascript with that tagging, so I tried it. Clearly to no avail. I just didn't want to waste time without trying everything I could find. The current setup is just the `<script type="text/javascript">` to the `<script>` portion without the php rendering that Joomla's documentation suggested. Still doesn't work. I've tried it every way I've thought possible.

Answer (score 0):

Put the following inside your module.

```
<?php

// Get the email from the url
$jinput = JFactory::getApplication()->input;
$recipient = $jinput->get('email', '', 'string');

$mailer = JFactory::getMailer();

$config = JFactory::getConfig();
$sender = array(
    $config->get( 'config.mailfrom' ),
    $config->get( 'config.fromname' )
);

$mailer->setSender($sender);

$mailer->addRecipient($recipient);

$body = '<h2>Thank you for joining our mailing list!</h2>'
        .'<div>Here is your coupon for a FREE 8" 1-topping pizza at Goodfellas!'
        .'<img src="http://www.goodfellas309.com/main/images/pizzacoupon.jpg" alt="pizza coupont"/></div>';

$mailer->isHTML(true);
$mailer->Encoding = 'base64';
$mailer->setSubject('Your Free Pizza!');
$mailer->setBody($body);

$send = $mailer->Send;
if ( $send !== true ) {
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">Error sending email: ' . $send->__toString() . '</script>';
} else {
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("An email with your coupon has been sent to you! Thank you for joining our mailing list!");</script>';
}
```

***Note:*** Depending on where you're putting this code you might need an extension like [this one](https://www.nonumber.nl/extensions/sourcerer) to make the php run.